# Thread with (textView and progressbar)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, textview

I am programming an app in Android, where I obtain the data from the microphone, it works fine, I am able to save the amplitude of the sound. And I can update the progresssbar.

```
  barraThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            while (isRecording){
                actualizarBarra(getAmplitud()); 
                //lector.setText(String.valueOf(getAmplitud()));

            }   
        }   
    },"barra Thread");
```

-Where: actualizarBarra(getAmplitud()); update the value of the progressbar with the actual amplitude.

My problems is that if I try to update a textView from that point, I get the error (

> “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.”

So I tried to update the textView using a "Handler" and also using "runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {..." but the app runs very slow and sometime crash. Do you know any way to update the progressbar and the textview at the same time, in a properly way?,

### Thanks a lot

Using the the runOnUiThread solution.

```
private void actualizarInterfaz() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {   
                actualizarBarra(getAmplitud());
                    lector.setText(String.valueOf(getAmplitud()));
            }
        });
    }
```

and then in a loop:

```
 while(isRecording){
   actualizarInterfaz(); 
 }
```

Was no error, just the app get frozen, so I can not see any log at the LogCat, just like is running normally but in fact does not.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you tried to update the views on the ui thread?  Also, what was the crash that you were getting when trying to do this?

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with that information. Is not really a crash is that the app get frozen. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update TextView on the UI (main) thread only. The handler approach is ok (there are others). As for the performance issue, I suspect the recording make too many frequent updates. Try to introduce delay in updating the view and not update it every time